# End of the line symbol in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I'm using liquibase in springboot app.
I'm inserting data in DB (postgres) with migration script.

The problem:
i have long string to insert in DB and i use '\n' to break in on lines.
Like following:

```
insert into public.long_string (id, header, content) values
    ('string1', 'header1',
     'Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5'\nLine6.')
;
```

But in DB i have Stored following:

```
'Line1\\nLine2\\nLine3\\nLine4\\nLine5'\\nLine6.'
```

And the same i have in response on front-end request.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying after executing the provided insert statement the `\n` turns to `\\n` in DB? OR have you yourself inserted `\\n` in DB? Sorry it's bit confusing for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I tested using this changset with Postgres, but I was unable to recreate your issue:

```
- changeSet:
   id: insert-table-test3
   author: XYZ
   changes:
     - sql:
        sql: insert into test3 (column1) values ('Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6.');
```

This was inserted 'Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6.', as expected.

Can you provide your entire changeset so it can be reviewed?  Also I noticed you have an extra single-quote after the 5 in your example.  I had to remove that to run the changeset.

Comment: I'm using .sql migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
'E'
```

added before inserted string contains special symbols.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE

like:

```
insert into public.long_string (id, header, content) values
    ('string1', 'header1',
     E'Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5'\nLine6.')
;
```